# How to assign static values into the query result - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have this site which has a select box containing:

```
1
2
3
4
```

But I want to change them into a static value like:

```
Travel
Housing
Gourmet
Medical
```

There is no specified field name in the database, like Travel,etc. It's purely number. So I have to assign static values representing each number.

The only field names in the db is `id, industry_id, company_name`. the one I specified above(numbers 1-4) are `industry_id`.

In my **Controller:**

```
$params["filter"] = $this->Users->get_category();
```

**Model:**

```
$sql = "SELECT industry_id FROM company GROUP BY industry_id ORDER BY industry_id ASC";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->result();
```

**View:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="field">
<?php foreach($filter as $cat)
{ 
    echo '<option value="'.$cat->industry_id.'">'.$cat->industry_id.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Sooo what is the field name of the name like Travel etc... Add that into your select and use it when building your option list with the id and display of the name.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw sorry, I forgot to specify that there's no field name of the name like Travel, etc in the db.. it's purely just number.

Comment: So you have a table with industry ID's that have no meaning? You don't know what the ID is for??? I disbelieve... there must be some description somewhere "related" to those ID's.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw the only field name in the db is id, industry_id, company_name. the one I specified above(numbers 1-4) are industry_id.

Comment: So you've updated your question saying there isn't any such names... How do you know what they are? The only way to do this then would be to create a table that has the ID and a Name and use it :) Are there any other tables?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I am not allowed to do that. There are some tables but does not contain any descriptions alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about that

```
$sql = "SELECT industry_id, CASE WHEN industry_id = 1 THEN 'Travel' WHEN industry_id = 2 THEN 'Housing' WHEN industry_id = 3 THEN 'Gourmet' WHEN industry_id = 4 THEN 'Medical' END AS industry_description  FROM company GROUP BY industry_id ORDER BY industry_id ASC";
```

> Be aware if industry_id is an INT this code should work - if its a VARCHAR you have to use e.g. `WHEN industry_id = '1'`

and in your view you simply access to `industry_description`

```
<select class="form-control" name="field">
<?php foreach($filter as $cat)
{ 
    echo '<option value="'.$cat->industry_id.'">'.$cat->industry_description.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Very elegant and keeps things all together nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = array();
$b = ['Travel', 'Housing', 'Gourmet','Medical'];
$i = 0;
foreach ($filter as $cat) {
    $a[$cat->industry_id] = $b[$i];
    $i++;
}

?>
<select class="form-control" name="field">
    <?php foreach ($a as $k => $val) {
        echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $val . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```